# Need the link and the text from the website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I just get ouput as below however looking for CVE-2022-1285

CVE-2022-1285
None

```
url ='https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/full-listing/2022/6'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(response.text,'html.parser')
for cve in soup.find_all('span',class_='col-md-2'):
        print(cve.text, cve.get('href'))
```

Comment: I meant looking for below output  cve..   url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to extract the link from the `span` element, you can grab the `a` tag` and use the same method.  For example:

```
url ='https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/full-listing/2022/6'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(response.text,'html.parser')
for cve in soup.find_all('span',class_='col-md-2'):
        print(cve.text, cve.a.get('href'))
        # link =  cve.a.get('href')
        # print(link)
```

Comment: I saved one line :)

Comment: url ='https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/full-listing/2022/6'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(response.text,'html.parser')
for cve in soup.find_all('span',class_='col-md-2'):
        link = cve.a.get('href')
        print(cve.text, link)

Comment: @vicky  I split them up so it would be clear to you or anyone else what I was doing... I saved 2 lines :)